# More variables in one data frame than the other data frame-- Using R

Tags: r

I am using NHANES demographic data from 2011-2016. I've managed to download all 3 datasets, however can't seem to merge all three due to NHANES 2011-2012 having 48 variables, while the other 2 have 47. Problem is, I've tried to not include it, but I need the number of people 18+ in this question to be included in my data. How else can I merge the if the number of variables dont match? Tried R-bind, c-bind, merge, and various things. I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
****

           See code below:
           library(haven)
           nhanes = read_xpt('https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2011-2012/DEMO_G.XPT')                
           nhanes2 = read_xpt('https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2013-2014/DEMO_H.XPT') 
           nhanes3 = read_xpt('https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.XPT')

           totalnhanes <- rbind(nhanes,nhanes2,nhanes3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the missing variables and set all values to NA:

```
setdiff(names(nhanes), names(nhanes2))
#[1] "RIDEXAGY"

nhanes2$RIDEXAGY <- NA

setdiff(names(nhanes), names(nhanes3))
#[1] "RIDEXAGY"

nhanes3$RIDEXAGY <- NA

totalnhanes <- rbind(nhanes,nhanes2,nhanes3) # Works. :)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `bind_rows` and any missing column (matched by column name) will be filled with NA.

```
library(dplyr)

df<-bind_rows(nhanes,nhanes2,nhanes3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rbindlist from data.table can serve the purpose.

```
library(haven)
library(data.table)
nhanes = read_xpt('https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2011-2012/DEMO_G.XPT')                
nhanes2 = read_xpt('https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2013-2014/DEMO_H.XPT') 
nhanes3 = read_xpt('https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.XPT')

l <- list(nhanes,nhanes2,nhanes3)
totalnhanes <- rbindlist(l, fill = TRUE)
```